# Javascript function, extend an object with an extension

Tags: javascript

This piece of code is from Addy Osmani's online book, "[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)".

```
// Extend an object with an extension
function extend( extension, obj ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}
```

It claims it can extend an object with an extension. It work well in the sample on the book. The `controlCheckbox` can function well for both definitions, `Subject` and DOM `checkbox`.

```
<input id="mainCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
...
var controlCheckbox = document.getElementById( "mainCheckbox" ),
...
extend( new Subject(), controlCheckbox );
...
controlCheckbox["onclick"] = new Function( "controlCheckbox.Notify(controlCheckbox.checked)" );
```

But I just can't get the point why it is **extended**? The function definition of `extend` looks like **overrding**, instead of **extending**, `controlCheckbox` from an DOM `checkbox` to `Subject`, in my poor eyes. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
function extend( extension, obj ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}

var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    extension = { b: 20, c: 30 };

console.log("Before: ", obj);
extend(extension, obj);
console.log("After: ", obj);
```

Output:

```
Before:  Object {a: 1, b: 2} 
After:  Object {a: 1, b: 20, c: 30}
```

It's easy to see what's happened:

1. Field `a` didn't exist in `extension`, so it remained **unchanged**.
2. Field `b` existed in both objects, so it was **overwritten** by `extension`'s field `b`.
3. Field `c` existed only in `extension`, so it was **added** to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

What `extend` does is add all attributes from `extension` to `obj` and overwrite the ones already existing.

When you say `obj['attr'] = 'foo'` in javascript, you create the attribute `attr` in the object `obj` and assign `foo` to it. If `attr` already exists in `obj`, you will overwrite it with `foo`.

An alternative syntax would be `obj.attr='foo'`, but this way, you can't use dynamic attribute names (variables, like in your example `key` is)

Some useful links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Comment: The explanation is okay, but that link is anything but "official".

Comment: @bfavaretto better now? ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks! Don't get me wrong, but w3schools' content quality is questionable, and, despite the name, it's not affiliated with the w3c. MDN (a wiki) is a better reference.